# How to change a f:field (textField) by a textArea using Grails Fields Plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

In the [documentation changelog of the plugin](http://freeside.co/grails-fields/guide/single.html#introduction), at Version 1.1, we can read:

```
Support `widget:'textarea'` constraint.
```

Grails has a textArea field. This is the example of the [grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/textArea.html):

```
<g:textArea name="myField" value="myValue" rows="5" cols="40"/>
```

But, if we are using Grails Fields Plugin, and we have a code like:

```
<f:field  bean="popularExpressionsInstance" property="omg" />
```

How could we convert it to textArea to allow to type several lines of text?

Answer (score 4):

In your `popularExpressions` domain class, add the following constraint for `omg`

```
static constraints = {
  ...
  omg widget: 'textarea'
}
```

Note: if you need to control style of textarea, you'll need to include it in the body of the `f:field` tag, for example

```
<f:field  bean="popularExpressionsInstance" property="omg">
  <g:textArea name="omg" cols="40" rows="5" maxlength="40" value="some default text"/>
</f:field>
```

Comment: Thank you! But just with `... <textarea rows="5" cols="40"></textarea> </f:field>`, the field become a textArea. Why the constraint is for?

Comment: @chelder if you define it in your constraint with `widget: 'textarea'` you are telling Grails how you want that property to be rendered in Scaffolding. If you use the default scaffolding Grails will generate a textarea for that property. For your use-case it might not be necessary.

Comment: Please, change `<textarea...` by `<g:textArea name="omg" cols="40" rows="5" maxlength="40" value="some default text"/>`. If not, the submitted value of the form is always null.

Answer (score 1):

You can override body of tag directly in GSP, as @user2264997 mentioned, but use `${ property }` and `${it.value}`  variables:

```
<f:field property="description" widget="textarea">
    <g:textArea name="${ property }" cols="40" rows="5"
        value="${it.value}" />
</f:field>
```